# Como centralizar um iframe?

Tags: css, iframe, animação

Tenha no minha pagina um banner animado que fiz no Google Web Designer que incrementei no meu site para aparecer antes de carregar a pagina index. Até ai tudo bem, os códigos estão funcionando mas gostaria de saber como eu poderia centralizar ela na pagina, de preferencia de forma interativa, pois o mesmo aparece no canto superior esquerdo e não consegui centralizar ele.
os codigos que estou usando são esses:

```
<style>
#conteudo1{ display:none; }
.asd {
display: nome;
background: black;
border: none;
height: 450px;
width: 900px;
align: center;
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('conteudo1').style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('carregando').style.display = "none";
}, 0000);
}
</script>
```

e na pagina coloquei a animação no começo para carregar a pagina em baixo e quando ele fechar puxar a pagina para cima com o script a cima citado

```
<body>
<div id="carregando" class="center">
<iframe class="asd" align="top" src="CSS/animation/index/index.html"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="conteudo1">...
```

Answer (score 3):

ja consegui, para quiser eu só adicionei um align center na div e middle no iframe assim:

```
<div id="carregando" class="center" align="center">
<br><br><iframe class="asd" src="CSS/animation/index/index.html" align="middle"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O elemento `<iframe>` é nativamente `inline-block`, ao menos nos navegadores modernos, nos mais antigos (antigos como IE6, etc) provavelmente deviam ser `inline`, todavia sendo `inline-block` ou `inline` ambos são alinhados usando `text-align: center;` se adicionando ao elemento "pai".

Você usou `algin: center;`, isto não existe, uma outra nota é que `align="center"` pode funcionar, mas é considerado obsoleto:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-23180977
- https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#adef-align-TABLE

Então para corrigir basta trocar o atributo errado `algin: center;` por `text-algin: center;`:

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.container > iframe {
    background: black;
    border: none;
    height: 450px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

No entanto se o iframe estiver com `display: block;` (pelo seu `setTimeout`) então não precisa do `text-align: center;` no elemento pai, basta adicionar `margin: 0 auto;` no iframe:

```css
.asd {
    background: black;
    border: none;
    height: 450px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* alinha o iframe */
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="carregando">carregando...</div>
<iframe class="asd" id="conteudo1" src=""></iframe>

<script>

setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('conteudo1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('carregando').style.display = "none";
}, 1000);
</script>
```